# How to set Data in Spinner from SQLite database?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

i want to set data on spinner from database in android... i have 6 column in database an i want to set 3 column in spinner. how to do that help me...

i search for that but i m not get any thing help me..

and yes can i sat below data in edit text and spinner too....

i got in this database
country name 
country iso
country phonecode

```js
AppDatabase db = new AppDatabase(getApplicationContext());
  db.open();
  // Log.e("", simCountry);
  Cursor cr = db.fetchAlertWhere(AppDatabase.User_table, 0, "iso = '"
    + simCountry + "'", "");
  // Log.e("This is data", "----" + cr.getString(2));

  cr.moveToFirst();
  if (cr != null) {
   do {
    for (int i = 0; i < cr.getColumnCount(); i++) {

     Log.e("data", "--" + cr.getString(i));
    }
   } while (cr.moveToNext());
  }
```

Comment: get data from database and store that data in Arraylist and set arraylist adapter to spinner..

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<String> country=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> countryarray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
```

**In cursor loop(if (cr != null) {)**

```
 country.add(cr.getString(i))
```

At end setadapter with spinner

```
spinner.setAdapter(country);
```